# Shift scheduling with Or-Tools: workers skills

Tags: c++, scheduling, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I'm trying to add skills to [this nurses scheduling example](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling).

My case: I have three shifts per day, each shift can have multiple nurses but at least one nurse needs to have a skill A (e.g. Nurse Senior) and at least one nurse needs to have a skill B (e.g. a Nurse Manager). One nurse can have skill A and skill B at the same time to satisfy my requirements. How can I specify this?

This is what I have so far:

```
const int num_workers = 5;
const int num_shifts  = 3;
const int num_days    = 2;

std::vector<std::vector<int>> skills = {
  // A, B
  {1, 0},
  {1, 0},
  {1, 1},
  {0, 1},
  {0, 0},
};

std::vector<int> all_workers(num_workers);
std::iota(all_workers.begin(), all_workers.end(), 0);

std::vector<int> all_shifts(num_shifts);
std::iota(all_shifts.begin(), all_shifts.end(), 0);

std::vector<int> all_days(num_days);
std::iota(all_days.begin(), all_days.end(), 0);

CpModelBuilder cp_model;

std::map<std::tuple<int, int, int>, IntVar> shifts;
for (int n : all_workers)
{
    for (int d : all_days)
    {
        for (int s : all_shifts)
        {
            auto key    = std::make_tuple(n, d, s);
            shifts[key] = cp_model.NewBoolVar().WithName(absl::StrFormat("shift_n%dd%ds%d", n, d, s));
        }
    }
}

// define min and max nurses for each shift
const std::array min_workers = {1, 2, 2};
const std::array max_workers = {3, 3, 3};

for (int d : all_days)
{
    for (int s : all_shifts)
    {
        std::vector<IntVar> x;
        for (int n : all_workers)
        {
            auto key = std::make_tuple(n, d, s);
            x.push_back(shifts[key]);
        }

        cp_model.AddLessOrEqual(min_workers[s], LinearExpr::Sum(x));
        cp_model.AddLessOrEqual(LinearExpr::Sum(x), max_workers[s]);
    }
}

// define shifts skills requirements
...
```

I know I need to make a sum of specific skill over all working nurses for each shift and for each day, but how can I define it?

I have more code done (like max hours per month, nurses requests, max one shift per day) but it's not important for skills.

Thanks.

Comment: have you checked the shift_scheduling_sat.py example ?

Comment: I have checked that. The answer might be there but I was not able to find it. I'll give it another try

Comment: If for a shift s, you need a person of type A, and a person of type B (could be the same), just write sum(persons_of_type_a) == s and sum(persons_of_type_b) == s.